# Why do options sometimes appear grey in the context menu even when they are available?

Tags: nautilus, menu

I can't determine when, but often the context menu shows options in gray when they shouldn't because they are activated and you can used them. I have seen this with resize, with paste (after copying files) and with  "create new folder" in a mounted partition. The partition wasn't protected by permissions and a few seconds later or in another window I could do the operation.

Can that be fixed? I find it annoying and confusing.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in 12.04 that's been around for  quite awhile & probably will be for some time. (showed up early in Feb.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/973491

Comment: Wow, how bad! That sounds terrible for Linux's prestige.

Comment: @Robert It's kind of standard. Bugs happen even in non-gratis software. The best one can ask for is that they patch these minor problems.